# what will happen to the socket if bind, listen, or accept fails

Tags: sockets

when i read APUE, it says

> SUS warns that the state of the socket is undefined if connect fails

but there is no specific description about the state of socket if bind, listen, or accept fails.
so i wonder whether the socket is still valid if bind, listen, or accept fails?

Comment: APUE = Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment, by W. Richard Stevens (for those who might be wondering)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- If `bind()` fails it isn't bound. You could call `bind()` on it again, or `connect()`.
- If `listen()` fails it isn't listening. You could connect it, or try `listen()` again if you're feeling lucky.
- If `accept()` fails it is still listening.
- `connect()` is an exception to all this. All you can do is close it.

Note that in all cases the socket is 'still valid'. It's just that it's unusable after a failed connect. You still have to close it. [The reason, or at least *a* reason, is that it may have been automatically bound to a local interface chosen as part of the route to the desired connect target, which may not be appropriate for a subsequent connect to a different target.]